# What does "Matches restricted index pattern defined in the cluster setting mean?

Tags: kibana, opensearch

I am trying to apply a policy to an index in OpenSearch

```
   POST _opendistro/_ism/add/.kibana_1
{
  "policy_id": "test"
}
```

.kibana_1 is an index that automatically got created even though I am not using Kibana.
I wanted to write an auto delete policy using ISM to delete if this index gets over 20GB.
But I get this error when i try to attach the policy to this index

> {   "updated_indices" : 0,   "failures" : true,   "failed_indices" : [
> {
> "index_name" : ".kibana_1",
> "index_uuid" : "someuuid",
> "reason" : "Matches restricted index pattern defined in the cluster setting"
> }   ] }

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue on opensearch 1.3.x.

The issue is because of a setting for index state management that restricts the ISM policies from being applied to certain index patterns:

```
plugins.index_state_management.restricted_index_pattern
```

The default value includes `.opendistro_security`, `.kibana*`, and `,opendistro-ism-config`.

Annoyingly, the setting doesn't seem to appear in the official docs but you can find it by checking all the cluster settings `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults=true&flat_settings`.

The fix is to put the setting on the `opensearch.yml` config or hit `PUT _cluster/settings` and adjust the setting value.

```json
{
  "persistent": {
    "plugins.index_state_management.restricted_index_pattern" : ".opendistro_security|.opendistro-ism-config"
  }
}
```